# Problema ao fazer insert em tabela no Postgresql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Quando vou fazer um `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO categoria (cat_descricao,cat_status) VALUES ('não' ,'1' )
```

passando por parâmetro algum elemento com acentuação é ocorrido o seguinte erro

> ERROR: 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0x6f 0x27>

Porém se eu fizer a instrução `SQL` no proprio `SGBD` ele vai normal sem nenhum problema, mas quando retorno essa informação através de um `DataTable` ela tbm aparece com valores trocados. Estou utilizando o `PostGres` e `C#`

```
public int ExecutarSQL(string sSQL)
{
    int iLinhas = 0;
    if (ConectaBanco())
    {
        _comando.CommandText = sSQL;
        iLinhas = _comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DesconectaBanco();
    }
    return iLinhas;
}
```

Ao realizar essa função ocorre o erro no `ExecuteNonQuery`, aparentemente aparenta ser um erro de UTF, porém o banco aceita então o problema é na linguagem? qual medida pode ser abordada afim de resolver esse problema?

Comment: Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere o `encondig` para `latin1` com o comando abaixo:

```sql
update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('LATIN1') 
where datname = 'nomedoBanco';
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema utilizando esse comando, obrigado !